# How render data from array in ng-container Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I want to render data from array into HTML table. Here's my model:

```
export class Section {
    public id :number;
    public name: string;
    constructor(id: number, theName: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = theName;
    }
}
```

I import it and fill it in the component:

```
import { Section } from "../models/registerSection.model";
```

Array declaration:

```
sectionList: Array<Section>;
```

Array is filled in constructor:

```
    this.sectionList = [new Section(1, "A"),
        new Section(2, "B*"),
        new Section(3, "C"),
        new Section(4, "D")];
```

This is how I'm trying to render data in template:

```
        <ng-container *ngFor='let data of Section'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">{{data.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
```

But the table is empty. In DOM, I see the following:

```
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->
```

What am I doing wrong? In debugging I can see that array contains data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let data of sectionList'>
```

Right now, you are trying to iterate through `Section` model, not `sectionList` which is instance of that model.